# Conflicting views on transformation of graphs question.

Tags: linear-transformations

myself and a colleague have inherited an exam paper previously used last year for our class and are facing a bit of dispute over naming the function.

The question is written as follows:

- the graph is concave upwards
- the graph is translated 3 units to the right
- the graph is stretched by scale factor 2 in x-axis.

Excuse the poor terminology. They have only looked at quadratics, so concave implies $x^2$.

My colleague has taken the view that the function should be written as

$ f(x) = ( \frac{1}{2} x - 3 )^2 $

However, I argue that it should be $ f(x) = ( \frac{1}{2} (x-3) ) ^2 $.

I am aware given a  function $ f(x) $ that has been transformed by $a f(bx + c ) + d $ that the order of transformations should follow $ c, b, a, d $. I can see merit in his answer. But I would argue that since the stretch follows that it means stretching the new substitute of  $x-3$ in place of $x$ .

Can anyone shed any light on how they would answer this question? It is poorly written, but I am worried I may just be making a silly error.

Comment: It depends if you "strech" from zero or arround the minimum of the parabola (3 in this case). In one case the root is translated, in the other it isn't. So it depends on the definition of "streching"

Comment: I agree with [Theleb](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/712699/theleb)—as given, the question is hopelessly ambiguous.  Your version of the stretch leaves the abscissa of the minimum fixed at $3$, your colleague's leaves the abscissa of the point where $\ y=9\ $ fixed at zero.  I really can't see why either of these points should be preferred to the other, or to any other point on the graph for that matter, as the one whose abscissa you choose to leave fixed.  I'd suggest rewording the description of the third step to make it clear which point must keep a fixed abscissa during the stretch